# Rename file when extracting using 7 zip command line

Tags: batch-file, command-line, 7zip

I'm using the following command to unzip a file:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x "\\server\folder\backup.gz" -aoa "-o\\server\folder\"
```

I've been on the 7-zip help section and the examples for using -aoa aren't very clear. Using Google I can see solutions on a website called sevenzip, but it's not available. I also thought I could use the rn command but I wasn't sure where to place it.

Comment: No problems here getting to the [7zip](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/index.htm) help site. The `-aoa` switch overwrites.  The `-aou` renames the extracted file if it already exists in the target directory. The `-aot` renames the existing file in the target directory.

Comment: Sorry, I meant this website which seems to have a more thorough answers. https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/commands/rename.htm the 7zip website is just similar to the help docs. If using -aou, where do I specify what I want the file to be called?

Comment: You don't.  The help clearly states it will add `_1` to the base file name depending on which switch you use.

Answer (score 8):

I was searching for a solution myself. Of course, extracting a file to a completely different filename only makes sense if you're only extracting *one* file.

What I ended up doing was to extract to standard out (`-so`) and redirecting the output to the desired name:

```
  7z e my-compressed-file.7z -so readme.txt > new-filename.txt
```

Comment: no need to put "readme.txt" there. the command `7z e -so file.7z > newfile.ext` works nicely ;) and thanks for that! really did the trick here!

Comment: Unfortunately redirecting the file via standard output results in a file with current timestamp instead of original timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

Made some tweaks to Mark's scripts. For some more advanced use.

```
for %%f in (folder\*.7z) do (7z e "%%f" -so -r *filename1*.jpeg *filename2*.jpg > tmp\%%f.jpg)
```

- now loops through multiple source files `for %%f in (folder\*.7z)`
- wildcard for the source file with optional sub-folder `folder\*.7z`
- multiple specific extracted files with wildcards `*filename1*.jpeg *filename2*.jpg`
- searches inside the source file recursively `-r`
- output file is named the same as input source file with optional sub-folder `tmp\%%f.jpg`